# I want to know the use of these options in firefox "Web Developer Toolbar"

Tags: javascript, css, firefox, xhtml, web-developer-toolbar

I want to know the use of these options in "[Web Developer Toolbar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/60/)"

Disable > Disable Javascript > Strict Warnings

Disable > Meta Redirects

Disable > Meta Referers

Disable > Disable minimum Font size

CSS > Use border box model

Information > Display Table Information

Information > Display Table Depth

Miscellaneous > Show Comments

Miscellaneous > Show Hidden Elements

Miscellaneous > Show Window Chrome

Miscellaneous > Linearize Page

Comment: I think all of these options are quite self-explanatory, and for the ones you don't understand, Google is your friend.

Comment: @Fabien If you look at his question history, I think most of them could be answered by Google :)

Comment: @Josh Stodola - if you look at all questions on SO , I think above 50% could be answered by Google :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For "Disable > Disable Javascript > Strict Warnings":-
The JavaScript Strict Warnings will not work from now on.

For "Disable > Meta Redirects":-
The HTML Meta Redirects will not work from now on, which would otherwise cause the page to reload or redirect.

For "Disable > Meta Referers":-
The HTML Meta Referers will not work from now on, which would otherwise provide access to the referring page's URI.

For "Disable > Disable minimum Font size":-
It disables the font sizes to be as small as the developer wants.

For "CSS > Use border box model":-
It uses the box model used before IE6. When enabled, border and padding values are counted inside the width value. If not enabled, the default & correct behavior will be used, where borders and paddings are counted outside of the width. **This is correct as mentioned by "Delan".**

For "Information > Display Table Information":-
It shows the HTML "Table" element's "Summary" attribute in a highlighted manner.

For "Information > Display Table Depth":-
It shows each HTML "Table" element's nesting depth. For example, if only 1 "table" element is used, then it highlights "Depth=1". If there is 1 more "table" element inside its parent "table" element, then it will highlight "Depth=2", and so on.

For "Miscellaneous > Show Comments":-
It will show all the HTML Comments, by highlighting a "!" character. So when the mouse is clicked upon that character, the comment gets shown.

For "Miscellaneous > Show Hidden Elements":-
It will unhide all the HTML elements, which have the CSS property "visibility:hidden".

For "Miscellaneous > Show Window Chrome":-
Unsure, but I think it will show the web page just like as it were in the Chrome browser.

For "Miscellaneous > Linearize Page":-
It will make all the HTML elements shown as "display:inline", **as mentioned by "Delan"**.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

*Disable > Disable Javascript > Strict Warnings* turns off strict warnings that relate to minor 'bad practices' in JavaScript code. They are safe to be ignored, as they are quite picky.

*Disable > Meta Redirects* stops a page with a *refresh* header in a `meta` tag from being enacted, which would otherwise cause the page to reload or redirect.

*Disable > Meta Referers* stops the page from having access to the referring page's URI.

*Disable > Disable minimum Font size* allows font sizes to be as small as the developer wants.

*CSS > Use border box model* uses the box model used before IE6. When enabled, border and padding values are counted *inside* the width value. If not enabled, the default, correct behaviour will be used, where borders and paddings are counted outside of the width.

*Information > Display Table Information* (unsure)

*Information > Display Table Depth* (unsure)

*Miscellaneous > Show Comments* will turn HTML comments into visible elements.

*Miscellaneous > Show Hidden Elements* will unhide elements with `visibility:hidden;`

*Miscellaneous > Show Window Chrome* (unsure)

*Miscellaneous > Linearize Page* will make all elements `display:inline;`